# Form control embedded to DS visible property

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I added the SalesId control to form from CustInvoiceTable DS.

The control is not visible even with code in CustInvoiceTable DS active method.

```
CustInvoiceTable_ds.object(fieldNum(CustInvoiceTable, SalesId)).visible(true);
```

in AOT CustInvoiceTable.SalesId visible property is set to 'no'. If I change it to Yes, then the control is visible in the form.

Is there a way to leave SalesId visible 'no' in table and using code set it to visible(true) on form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help on the Visible property of a fields reads:

> Determines whether the field should be visible in the user interface.

If set the field is *not* shown in forms or reports, nor can it programmatically forced visible (other than changing the field property!).

The only other option is to make a display method, but in this case make the field visible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set control visibility (instead DataSource).

If control has `AutoDeclaration` set to `Yes` you can access [`visible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formstringcontrol.visible.aspx) property.

```cs
controlName.visible(true);
```

---

Each form control is also accessible via `element`.[`control()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formrun.control.aspx) method.
*controlId* can be retrived by [`controlId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formrun.controlid.aspx) method.

For compile-time safty use [`formControlStr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg901176.aspx) function.

```cs
element
    .control(element.controlId(formControlStr(FormName, ControlName)))
    .visible(true);
```

Comment: If the table field's property is set to `Visible=No` this will not work.

Comment: @AlexK Then you have to set DataSource field `visible(true)`. This is cleared in the question.

Comment: I don't believe that will change it either.  Have you tried it?  Having the AOT table's field property to `Visible=false`?